# set CSS class of each column in the header of a datatable in JSF

Tags: css, jsf, datatable

Let's say I have a data table, I can put the CSS class in each column using the columnClasses, is there a similar way to set CSS class on every single column in the header? headerClass puts CSS class at all columns in the header and it's not what I want to do. I want to put unique CSS class of each column in the header.

An example of a datatable:

```
<h:dataTable columnClasses="column1,column2,column3">

    <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header" >
      </f:facet>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header" >
      </f:facet>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header" >
      </f:facet>
    </h:column>

</h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your style class for the component which your are using is

For eg:-

```
<f:facet  name="header" >
     <h:outputText value="Some Value" styleClass="myStyleClass"/>
</f:facet>
```